# Robot Framework- Loading Spinner selector

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have this problem where I have to validate if a loading spinner is present, it's present for about 1 second on the page, i have found the xpath selector of the loading spinner but selenium library could not find it is there another way to find out a selector of something that dissapears after a short while? *Note:* The xpath is definitely correct. There is no id on the loading spinner either.

This is the code i have tried

```
Validate Loading Spinner
    Wait until page contains  xpath=//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/svg
```

I have also tried `Element should contain` and `Page should contain` but that does not find the locator.

Comment: Please share the code you tried with. There are quite a few keywords for this kind of check (Element Should Be Visible, Page Should Contain, etc), plus different tactics to do the verification.

Comment: @Todor I have added the code sample i have ttied

Comment: Is the parent div of the svg precise enough to target it instead of the circle?

Comment: @Nomce I have tried both ways, no results, And yes svg should be enough to target, i have fixed the code.

Comment: To concentrate on the locator - such rigid structure - e.g. a specific number of `div` children -  is error prone, the slightest change in the app's DOM will break it. Say this exact locator is precise for the moment, and that's not the issue; there is a peculiarity with svg elements in xpath, most of the times it can't address them directly. Try with this - change the `div/svg` at the end with `div/*[local-name() = "svg"]`, and tell how it goes.

Comment: It's still failing with the same error `Page should have contained text 'xpath=//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/*[local-name() = "svg"] but did not.` I thinks its something to do with the time the spinner is visible for its only a second sometimes less and then it dissapears that said, the `<svg>` is still visible in the console

Comment: Hold, if you are checking with the [Page Should Contain](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Page%20Should%20Contain) keyword - it is looking for a specific text in the html, not for a locator. Wait for the element with the `Wait Until Element Is Visible`, or `Wait Until Page Contains Element` keywords.

Comment: @Todor Both fail with the same error `Element with locator 'css=#app > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.sidebar > div.sidebar__account > div > div.account__loggedin > a' not found.
`

Comment: ok, this is getting html specific - and the locator in the last comment is obviously not the xpath we discussed before that :)

Comment: Yes, it is somehow when i Use `Wait Until Element Is Visible` or `Wait Until Page Contains Element` it transform the xpath selector to a css selector :/

Comment: "... it transform the xpath selector to a css selector ... " which is simply impossible :) Check what variable are you using as an argument, you must have mistyped it.

Comment: Yup you are right... I was thinking of something else.. the spinner is validated now You should provide an answer for other people thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using one of the keywords that is validating an element is present - [Wait Until Element Is Visible](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Visible), or [Wait Until Page Contains Element](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Page%20Contains%20Element) - both of which support a `timeout` argument, for how much to wait.

Afterwards, you'd better use the opposite keyword - `Wait Until Element Is Not Visible`, to make sure the spinner disappears and you can continue with the test.

There is a problem with your locator - xpath has some issues if the element is `svg`, most of the times it can't address it directly. So instead of specifying it explicitly in the path, look for a node whose name happens to be "svg"; e.g.:

```
xpath=//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/*[local-name() = "svg"]
```

*(^ changed the last element in the path)*

---

Slightly offtopic - try to have less rigid locators - this one specifies an absolute path from the element with id "app" and down (a div child, then its first div child, then that one's third div child, and so on and so forth). If the element structure changes even slightly, the locator will stop working (say, in a bug fix, or re-positioning it, or just with using a HF of an JS library).
Try to find an element that's 1-2 levels higher than your target svg - by a solid class value, or structure that's unique, and use it as an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you used wrong keyword

```
Validate Loading Spinner
    Wait until page contains ELEMENT  xpath=//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/svg
```

Answer (score 0):

Both work:

> Validate Loading Spinner
>        wait until page contains element  xpath=//* 
>                [@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/*[local-name() = "svg"]

and

> Wait until page contains ELEMENT  xpath=//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/svg

I had a very similar issue